# How do I open a hamburger that doesn't want to be opened?

Tags: html, css

I have a codebase I inherited from a senior developer. I need help on opening up the hamburger when clicked(i.e on the mobile/responsive view).

The navbar works fine on desktop view but on mobile view it does not open.

I have been on this for hours to no avail

I have been talking to my computer and codebase for hours to have mercy on me

I am a junior developer hence my lack of vision to see the underlying problem.

Please What is wrong with my code?

```css
#navbar {
  color: white; 
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 10;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
} @media(max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-wrapper {
      width: 90%;
    }
  } @media(max-width: 638px) {
      .nav-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
      }
    } 


.logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  height: 60px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
} @media(max-width: 768px) {
    .logo {
/*       margin-left: 5px; */
    }
  }

#navbar ul {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  /* margin-right: 14px; */
  margin-top: -2px;
  text-align: right;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
} @media(max-width: 640px) {
    #navbar ul {
      display: none;
    }
  } @media(orientation: landscape) {
      #navbar ul {
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }

#navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#navbar li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(28, 121, 184); */
  color:white;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}

/* Animated Bottom Line */
#navbar li a:before, #navbar li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  background: white;
}

#navbar li a:before {
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

#navbar li a:after {
  background: rgb(13, 26, 38);
  right: 0;
  /* transition: width 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1); */
}

#navbar li a:hover:before {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.5s cubic-bezier((0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1));
}

#navbar li a:hover:after {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  /* transition: 0s; */
}



/*======================================================
                    Mobile Menu Menu Icon
  ======================================================*/
@media(max-width: 640px) {
  .menuIcon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
    top: 20px;
    height: 23px;
    width: 27px;
    z-index: 12;
  }

  /* Icon Bars */
  .icon-bars {
    background: rgb(13, 26, 38);
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    top: 45%;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
  } 

  .icon-bars::before {
    background: rgb(13, 26, 38);
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -8px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
/*     -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease 0.3s;
    transition: top 0.2s ease 0.3s; */
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s width 0.4s;
    transition: 0.3s width 0.4s;
  }

  .icon-bars::after {
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: rgb(13, 26, 38);
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -8px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
/*     -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease 0.3s;
    transition: top 0.2s ease 0.3s; */
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s width 0.4s;
    transition: 0.3s width 0.4s;
  }

  /* Bars Shadows */
  .icon-bars.overlay {
    background: rgb(97, 114, 129);
    background: rgb(183, 199, 211);
    width: 20px;
    animation: middleBar 3s infinite 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation: middleBar 3s infinite 0.5s;
  } @keyframes middleBar {
      0% {width: 0px}
      50% {width: 20px}
      100% {width: 0px}
    } @-webkit-keyframes middleBar {
        0% {width: 0px}
        50% {width: 20px}
        100% {width: 0px}
      }

  .icon-bars.overlay::before {
    background: rgb(97, 114, 129);
    background: rgb(183, 199, 211);
    width: 10px;
    animation: topBar 3s infinite 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation: topBar 3s infinite 0s;
  } @keyframes topBar {
      0% {width: 0px}
      50% {width: 10px}
      100% {width: 0px}
    } @-webkit-keyframes topBar {
        0% {width: 0px}
        50% {width: 10px}
        100% {width: 0px}
      }

  .icon-bars.overlay::after {
    background: rgb(97, 114, 129);
    background: rgb(183, 199, 211);
    width: 15px;
    animation: bottomBar 3s infinite 1s;
    -webkit-animation: bottomBar 3s infinite 1s;
  } @keyframes bottomBar {
      0% {width: 0px}
      50% {width: 15px}
      100% {width: 0px}
    } @-webkit-keyframes bottomBar {
        0% {width: 0px}
        50% {width: 15px}
        100% {width: 0px}
      }


  /* Toggle Menu Icon */
  .menuIcon.toggle .icon-bars {
    top: 5px;
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0) rotate(135deg);
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  }

  .menuIcon.toggle .icon-bars::before {
    top: 0;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .menuIcon.toggle .icon-bars::after {
    top: 10px;
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0) rotate(-270deg);
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  }

  .menuIcon.toggle .icon-bars.overlay {
    width: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0s ease 0s;
  }
}


/*======================================================
                   Responsive Mobile Menu 
  ======================================================*/
.overlay-menu {
  background: lightblue;
  color: rgb(13, 26, 38);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 15px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
}

.overlay-menu ul, .overlay-menu li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay-menu li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
/*   opacity: 0; */
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
/*   -webkit-transition: 0.2s opacity 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: 0.2s opacity 0.2s ease-out; */
}

.overlay-menu li a:hover,
.overlay-menu li a:active {
  color: rgb(28, 121, 184);
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar" class="">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <!-- Navbar Logo -->
    <div class="logo">
      <!-- Logo Placeholder  -->
      <img src="id logos.png">
    </div>

    <!-- Navbar Links -->
    <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="About Me.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="Portfolio page.html">Portfolio</a></li>
   
   
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<!-- Menu Icon -->
<div class="menuIcon">
  <span class="icon icon-bars"></span>
  <span class="icon icon-bars overlay"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `#navbar ul` selector has a media query that makes the menu invisible via `display: none;` when the screen's width is less than 640px. I presume that clicking the hamburger menu is supposed to make the menu visible again. Is there a part of your code that accomplishes this, or is that the missing link here?

Comment: I think that is the missing link, so how do you propose I correct that?

Comment: Do you have a corresponding javascript file that handles the click event?

Comment: No I don't. Do I need a js script to handle the click event? I thought css was sufficient to do the work. I think I see your point

Comment: Yes, effectively you do. you can do this in raw javascript or with a library like jQuery. I will post an example...

Answer (score 2):

You need a corresponding javascript event listener to trigger an active state on your menu...

Typically I do this by toggling a css class and let css transitions handle everything. Your code is a big wall of text, so I will just make up some markup as an example and you can apply it to your code however you want.

First, let's make some html:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="hamburger">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Now some crude css:

```
#menu{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    z-index:100;
    background:#000;
    padding:4rem;
    transition:.5s;
}

#menu.active{
    left:0;
}

#hamburger{
    position:relative;
    padding:.5rem;
    background:#000;
    z-index:101;
}

#hamburger span{
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    background:#fff;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    transition:.5s;
}

#hamburger.active span:nth-child(1){
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

#hamburger.active span:nth-child(2){
    width:0;
}

#hamburger.active span:nth-child(3){
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

Now some basic javascript listener (raw javascript):

```
document.getElementById('hamburger').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('hamburger').classList.toggle('active');
    document.getElementById('menu').classList.toggle('active');
});
```

For simplicity sake, this is a modern browser example. IE pre v10 probably wont handle this example, but that's another journey for you.

A jQuery example:

```
$('#hamburger').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#menu').toggleClass('active');
});
```

So to summarize, you basically have nothing listening on your hamburger. Either of these will probably work, but this is really just pseudo code. I tested nothing. But this is enough to run with for now. You should be able to get things moving with this example.

Answer (score 0):

### Add a Breakpoints

**Hope this will help you.Try media queries according to your device.**

Media queries can help with that. We can add a breakpoints where certain parts of the design will behave differently on each side of the breakpoints.

---

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>

<p>Resize the browser window. When the width of this document is 600 pixels or less, the background-color is "lightblue", otherwise it is "lightgreen".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Media query is a CSS technique introduced in CSS3.

It uses the @media rule to include a block of CSS properties only if a certain condition is true.

Comment: thanks...but that's not it. there are media queries there already. Its the hamburger icon that is not dropping down when clicked that is the problem. Try running the code snippet to see

Comment: got it man! sorry i actually didn't scroll down..looking more into your code know